# Get value from php to javascript using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have the following ajax script

```
 dataString = 'cipher'; //
    var jsonString = JSON.stringify(dataString);
       $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "tokenize.php",
            data: {data : jsonString}, 
            cache: false,

            success: function(){
                alert("OK");
            }
        });
       returnedvalue = result //I wanted to store the value returned by php in this variable
       alert(returnedvalue);
```

and the tokenize.php is

```
$data = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['data']));
return $data;  //Pass this value as ajaxs response
```

But im not able to get this.When I checked in the console I get error uncaught:result is not defined.

Im new to query,searched on google and done upto this.

The json is not necessary,all I wanted to do is pass a value to php and process it and give a rssponse back to teh javascript so that i can use it in the javascript

Comment: Use `echo $data;` instead of `result $data;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the parameter into the anonymous function for the `success` event.

```
success: function(data) {
    returnedvalue = data;
    console.log(data); //alert isn't for debugging
}
```

Comment: @PiyaSharma Is this works with return $data;,I think ou need to change it to echo $data; in your php file also

Answer (score 2):

You are passing just string(`dataString = 'cipher';`) into ajax file. There is no need to JSON.

> To use `echo` for return values from AJAX file.

**Update in JS:**

```
dataString = 'cipher'; //

       $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "tokenize.php",
            data: {data : dataString}, 
            cache: false,

            success: function(result) { //just add the result as argument in success anonymous function
                var returnedvalue = result;
                alert(returnedvalue);
            }
        });
```

**Update in PHP file:**

```
$data = stripslashes($_POST['data']);
echo $data;
```